# Taking elements from list after enumeration

Tags: python, list, csv, glob, enumerate

```
users = []
for t in enumerate(glob.glob('/Users/*/*_grounder.csv'), 1):
    for f in enumerate(glob.glob('/Users//*/*_pip.csv'), 1):
        if t != f:
            users.append((t, f)
```

With the code above I have a list with common numbers starting at 1 with this list I wish to take these CSV files from the list and make them into their own data frames OR merge them into one.

For example:

```
(1, file_grounder.csv), (1, file_pip,csv), 2, (etc,etc)
```

Takes the files with 1 in front of them and merge them from the list similar to how I globbed the folders for the files.

Comment: So what is your question? I did not get what you want to do. Also, I believe you wrote in the code `if t!= f:` and missed a space between variable `t` and the `!`

Comment: wish to merge the two csv's into one table for analyzing. I have assigned each file with a number using the enumerate function but now wish to pull these assigned files from the list for further analysis.